# How to access numpy ndarray of arbitrary rank whose shape is reduced in all dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reduce the size of an numpy ndarray of arbitrary rank by decreasing the upper limit of its shape in each dimension by one.  The array values should **not** move relative to their original index.

So,

```
    [N] becomes [N-1]
  [N,M] becomes [N-1, M-1]
[N,M,P] becomes [N-1, M-1, P-1], etc.
```

This should be handled by a function that does not know the array rank in advance.

```
import numpy as np

def truncator( array ):
   # flailing
   return truncated_array


>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> truncator(a)
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

I have thought about `reshape` and `resize` without success.  Knowing the array rank in advance I know how to use a view like `truncated_array = array[:-1,:-1]`, but I don't know how to make that concept work for arbitrary rank. Is there something like `Elipses`, `...`, with fixed width? That could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def truncator(array):
  new_shape = [d-1 for d in array.shape]
  return np.resize(array, new_shape)
```

hope this works.

edit : you didn't specified how the array should be truncated : if you just want a bunch of `:-1`s like `a[:-1,:-1:,-1]`:

```
def another_truncator(array):
  slicers = [slice(-1) for d in array.shape]
  return array[slicers]


>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
>>> another_truncator(a)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

what it does :

you can 'slice' an collection by `col[start:end:step]`. in fact the slice operator(`[::]`) used in `col[start:end:step]` can be represented as a `slice` object (`slice(start, end, step)`) and you can 'slice' the collection using that object like you do with integer indices.

to truncate an (possibly nested) array, you have to select every item except the last one - which is `[:-1]` - hence `slice(-1)`, and you have to do the selection for n times, n being the dimension of the array.

```
def another_truncator(array):
  slicers = [slice(-1) for d in array.shape] #create n slicers
  return array[slicers] #slice and return
```

Comment: thanks, but no. the resize operation shuffles the values around in the array, matching the original memory layout I think.  I tried a test case and it failed.

Comment: great. Thank you!  I'll clarify the question.  can you explain a little bit what the code is doing?

Comment: The answer also is creating a view on the original array, not a copy.  This is fine, i'm just pointing it out.

Comment: it shouldn't create a copy of an array since we're just slicing it. :D

Comment: Multidimensional indices are passed to the numpy object as a tuple. Numpy will often, like here, figure things out on its own, but indexing with lists or arrays is better kept for fancy indexing. Keeping the basic idea, you can get the OP's desired behavior in a single line as `arr[(slice(-1),) * arr.ndim]`.